# reloading a scroll view

Tags: swift, scrollview, xib

I added a scroll view in an UIViewController , and I set it content by using a xib file , so in the UIViewController there is an array(variable) and in it a content is added every time a button is pressed . In the xib file I loop through that array and I set it content in a label . My question is How do I reload the content of that label every time the button is pressed ?

Comment: Can we see the code you are currently using?

Comment: the code is just appending a content every time the button is pressed , but I do not know how to reload the content in the xib file including relooping into the array and setting it content in a label when the button is pressed